# Deploy a file in internal storage on debug

Tags: android, adt

I am developping an Android application with Eclipse.
I have chosen to store data of my application in an XML file in internal storage.

For debugging pupose, I would like to populate this data file by hand and to deploy it in internal storage on the device.

Is there a custom folder of my projet from which files will be copied in "internal storage" location when deploying / testing the app ?

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use the `/assets` folder of your project.

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/index.html :

> assets/
>   This is empty. You can use it to store raw asset files. Files that you save here are compiled into an .apk file as-is, and the original filename is preserved. You can navigate this directory in the same way as a typical file system using URIs and read files as a stream of bytes using the the AssetManager. For example, this is a good location for textures and game data.

Comment: Is the content of "Assets" deployed in the target "internal storage" folder ?
I mean, will I be able to modify these files then ?

Comment: I think you'll need to use the `AssetManager` to use the file.

Answer (score 0):

you can upload the files to the emulator using DDMS. Try this [link](http://www.anddev.org/tinytut_-_pull-push_files_from-to_the_emulator_eclipse-t113.html)